# How to nest loops N number of times python

Tags: python, loops, nested, nested-loops

I'm creating a program, which needs to nest loops N number of times. Is there any way to do this? Or do I need to do it manually?

Wanted result:

```
for i in range(N):
    #Do something
    for i in range(N-1):
        #Do something
        for i in range(N-2):
            #Etc, continues until the value in range is 0
```

Comment: What do you need N nested loops for? Most likely there is a way to do that without using N nested loops.

Comment: Maybe [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) ?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm creating a tic tac toe ai, which manually loops through all the possible ways, and chooses the best way to win (I'm doing this for a challenge so this has to be the way it gets its moves).

Comment: @AndrejKesely from the examples the docs are giving, I don't think it would work

Comment: @EbrahimMomin Better edit your question and put there small example of the problem and expected output.

Comment: @AndrejKesely done. Would iterables.product be able to do this task?

Comment: This reads like it might be trying to do the same as `itertools.permutations`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with recursion

```
def func(N)
    if N == 0: return
    for i in range(N):
        #do something
    return func(N-1)
```